# SQL Jobs or Task Scheduler call log4net, does not write log file

Tags: log4net

I write a console application with log4net, my log4net config below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="Process_Log\" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd.TXT" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %message [%logger] %n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Run the console application, It has output log files.
But use SQL Server Agent Jobs or Windows Task Scheduler call it,
It didn't write log file.

Comment: Does the service account used to call the application (ie the account the Agent or Scheduled job is running as) have the correct permissions to write to the file?

Comment: I've try to write a sample code, use StreamWriter to output a text file. 
called by SQL Agent, and has write a text file. 
I think the permission is correct.

Comment: Have you tried enabling log4net debugging and checking if it logs any errors? In your console application's .config file under `<appSettings>` add this: `<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>`, and you should see log4net debugging in the console. See [this page](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html) for more details on log4net debugging (under the section "How do I enable log4net internal debugging?").

Comment: I've tried this way, it didn't show any errors. It's helpful to find it out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out the problem. When you run the solution from Visual Studio, log4net finds out the configuration file from the "bin" folder. So, it gets required information to run. But when you run the application by  Windows Task Scheduler, the situation is different. This time, the  Windows Task Scheduler tries to find out the Configuration file from this location "C:\Windows\System32". Because, when you run Windows Task Scheduler, it treats the default application folder location "C:\Windows\System32".

You can write following codes to navigate the application to load the log4net configuration file. Here, the config file name is "LogConfiguration.config".

```
 var log4NetConfigDirectory =
       AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath ?? AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
 var log4NetConfigFilePath = Path.Combine(log4NetConfigDirectory, "LogConfiguration.config");
 log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(log4NetConfigFilePath));
```

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer by user3626918 is correct about the problem (wrong working directory).  As an alternative to the proposed code change solution you can instead:

- Configure the "Start in" directory of your scheduled task (Properties->Actions->Edit...)
- Confirm that the account running the scheduled task has permissions to write to the log file destination.